# vb.net find textbox name that begins with specified string in a TabControl

Tags: vb.net

I have a TabControl in a form with 4 tabpages. Each tabpage has multiple GroupBox. Each GroupBox has tableLayoutPanel. Each tableLayoutPanel has pragmatically generated array of textbox. if checkbox in a tableLayoutPanel is checked by the user then textboxes in the respective row will be generated. Suppose, the name of one of my textbox array is txtMax(0), txtMax(1).......upto txtMax(42). I need to know how many txtMax(?) (along with their index array) has been generated and become visible. I have tried the the following:

```
Dim coutGene as integer = 0
Dim coutParameter as integer = 0
Dim indx As Integer
Dim cntl1, cntl2, cntl3 As Control

For Each cnn As TabPage In tabParameters.TabPages
    cntl1 = DirectCast(cnn, TabPage)
    For Each c2 As Control In cntl1.Controls
        If TypeOf (c2) Is GroupBox Then
            cntl2 = DirectCast(c2, GroupBox)
            For Each c3 As Control In cntl2.Controls
                If TypeOf (c3) Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                    cntl3 = DirectCast(c3, TableLayoutPanel)
                    For Each c4 As Control In cntl3.Controls
                        If TypeOf (c4) Is TextBox Then
                            Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(c4, TextBox)
                                If txt.Name.StartsWith("txtMax") Then
                                    If txt.Visible = True Then
                                        indx = CInt(Between(txt.Name, "(", ")"))
                                        countGene = CInt(countGene + Val(txtGene(indx).Text))
                                        countParameter = countParameter + 1
                                        txtMax(indx).Tag = ""
                                    End If
                                End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

Function Between(value As String, a As String, b As String) As String
    ' Get positions for both string arguments.
    Dim posA As Integer = value.IndexOf(a)
    Dim posB As Integer = value.LastIndexOf(b)
    If posA = -1 Then
        Return ""
    End If
    If posB = -1 Then
        Return ""
    End If

    Dim adjustedPosA As Integer = posA + a.Length
    If adjustedPosA >= posB Then
        Return ""
    End If

    ' Get the substring between the two positions.
    Return value.Substring(adjustedPosA, posB - adjustedPosA)
End Function
```

But the every time code is not getting inside the loop for this condition **If txt.Name.StartsWith("txtMax") Then**

I am stuck up here. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Regards. Tariq

Comment: I suppose you have used the debugger to discover the code not entering the if condition. Then what is the value of txt.Name?

Comment: The condition does not find any textbox which name strats with txtMax. but i have made txtMax(1) visible. Eventhough the condition skips.

Comment: 1. Use a recursive function to iterate through the controls instead of the `For Each-es`. 2. This `indx = CInt(Between(txt.Name, "(", ")"))` is not possible, maybe you mean `indx = CInt(Between(txt.Text, "(", ")"))`

Comment: _txtMax_ seems to be the name of the array variable not the name of the TextBox controls stored in that array. Can you show the code where you build dynamically the TextBoxes and the code where you store those controls into the _txtMax_ array?

Comment: Maybe you just need to `For Each txt In txtMax.Where(Function(t) t.Visible) : ... : Next`

Comment: Also the code inside the Between method where you adjust the a position will make always true the condition _If adjustedPosA >= posB Then_

Comment: Your code is way more verbose than it needs to be. Firstly, what's the point of this: `cntl1 = DirectCast(cnn, TabPage)`? `cnn` is already type `TabPage` so the cast is pointless at least, and the `cntl1` variable is also probably pointless.

Comment: Also, there's no need to check the type of the control and then cast because you can use `OfType` to filter by type. Instead of `For Each c2 As Control In cntl1.Controls` use `For Each gb As GroupBox In cntl1.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()` and you now know that the loop control variable is a control of interest and it's already the right type. You can simplify that a little further by letting the type of the loop control variable to be inferred: `For Each gb In cntl1.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()`.

Comment: As for your issue, if the code finds no `TextBoxes` with that name then there are no `TextBoxes` with that name. Are you sure that you're actually setting the `Name` property of those controls? Maybe we should see the code that creates them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all yours guidelines and suggestion. I tried to implement all,,, but the code could not find the control even though the control exists and visible. I tried this simple code

```
For k = 1 To 42
    If txtMax(k).Visible = True Then
        countGene = CInt(countGene + Val(txtGene(k).Text))
        countParameter = countParameter + 1
        txtMax(k).Tag = ""
    End If
Next
```

But i find that, it search and count the control that exists only in the present tabpage of the TabControl. So i modified the code, though not efficient code, to solve my problem.
I have 4 tabpages in the TabControl. So i tried to select each tabpage by its index and searched 4 times.

```
For tp As Integer = 0 To 3
    tabParameters.SelectedIndex = tp
       For k = 1 To 42
          If txtMax(k).Visible = True Then
             countGene = CInt(countGene + Val(txtGene(k).Text))
             countParameter = countParameter + 1
             txtMax(k).Tag = ""
          End If
      Next
Next
```

Though i solved my problem, but still i seek your advise for efficient code.

Comment: `For k = 1 To 42`? What about the first text box in the array? `txtMax(0)`? you skip it. Use `For k = 0 To txtMax.Count -1 ...` instead. See the answer below for better approach.

Comment: The `TabControl` exists to make complex UIs simpler. It allows you to crowd far more controls into a space than you usually would. To prevent that from creating performance issues, the `TabControl` is designed such that the controls on a `TabPage` are not created until that `TabPage` is selected. You are seeing the effect of this. Those controls don't exist so you can't find them. I've often meant to try to find a way to force creation of those controls without selecting the `TabPages` but I've never got around to it because I haven't needed to for myself yet.

Comment: Thanks   @jmcilhinney.. for your knowledge sharing.  Thanks to JQSOFT also for his suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You should simplify that code to this:

```
For Each tp As TabPage In tabParameters.TabPages
    For Each gb In tp.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        For Each tlp In gb.Controls.OfType(Of TableLayoutPanel)()
            For Each tb In tlp.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(c) c.Visible AndAlso c.Name.StartsWith("txtMax"))
                'If you get here, tb is definitely a visible TextBox with a Name starting with "txtMax".
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

That code will find every visible `TextBox` with a `Name` that starts with ""txtMax" inside a `TableLayoutPanel`, inside a `GroupBox`, inside a `TabPage`, inside `tabParameters`, guaranteed. If that code doesn;t find any such controls, it's because there are no such controls, so that's what you need to investigate.